# how can i know whether a linux syscall is thread safe?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, thread-safety, system-calls

some functions in linux  mark "thread safe" by _r (e.g. gmtime_r ) 
but most of the syscalls are not be marked and also not mentioned in manpages.
So my question is :
How can i konw whether a linux syscall is thread safe?
Thank you!

Comment: Of the standard posix functions, all except these http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html#tag_02_09_01 , are thread-safe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you mean "library functions"; syscalls should, by virtue of operating on the thread's kernel-side data, be thread-safe.

And the answer is: check the manual pages for the functions in question. The "_r" variants are provided specifically for functions which were non-reentrant, meaning that the extra parameters passed to them were statically declared and modified in the non-"_r" versions.

Most of glibc should be, IIRC, thread-safe, but you *always* need to check manual pages; or, if you don't trust those, the code itself. There's no silver bullet that will remove from you the responsibility of understanding the interfaces which you are programming against.

Comment: +1 99.99% system calls on a multithreaded OS must be thread-safe by definition.  Any 'exotics', (maybe some debugging stuff, say), may be restricteed to only one thread in a process, but will surely be highlighted as such in the OS user manual/help/man whatever.  The default is 'thread-safe' - it just has to be else the OS would explode on boot.

Comment: thank you !  you means functions in sys/xxx.h  should be thread-safe.and others should refer to manpages ,Right?