# Is os.File's Write() threadsafe?

Tags: go

I was wondering if calling Write() on an os.File is thread safe.  I'm having a hard time finding any mention of thread safety in the docs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The convention (at least for the standard library) is the following: No function/method is safe for concurrent use unless explicitly stated (or obvious from the context).

It is not safe to write concurrently to an `os.File` via `Write()` without external synchronization.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a pointer to any place that the convention is mentioned?

Comment: No, sorry. I think this is just a convention.

Comment: for those who encounter this question, you can see in go 1.16 that `fd.writeLock();` is used in `Write(buf []byte)` function, so it seems that it uses internal synchronization

Answer (score 1):

After browsing the source code a little bit I found the following method which is eventually called by file.Write(). Since there are race condition checks in place, I'm assuming that the call is in fact not thread-safe within Go ([Source](http://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_unix.go?s=3386:3433#L138)).

However, it seemed unlikely that those system calls wouldn't be thread-safe on an OS level. After some browsing I came upon [this interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12025655/2544044) that fueled my suspicions even more. For windows the [source](https://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_windows.go) indicates a call to [WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/apps/aa365747.aspx) which also appears to be [thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894082/writefile-thread-safety).